# Identify which Chrome tab/site is using the webcam

Tags: linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webcam

For home automation purposes I'd like to programmatically monitor what's using my webcam. I can identify the relevant processes using `fuser /dev/video*` [1] but these days I run both Teams and Zoom as web apps [2] so this approach will only identify the single Chrome `VideoCaptureService` process in either case.

Is there any way to interrogate Chrome and **determine the web domain or title of the tab/window that has the webcam open?** This could be either from the outside, or I could write a Chrome extension - but I can't see anything to query webcam usage in these [extension docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/).

Identifying that one of these apps/sites is open is insufficient: I keep Teams open continuously in working hours to receive incoming calls.

[1] …or equivalent inspection of `/proc/*/fd/*`. On Windows one could probably use [this registry hackery](https://gist.github.com/cobryan05/8e191ae63976224a0129a8c8f376adc6).

[2] There are Linux-native versions of these available, but I think they're just Electron wrappers and the web apps in Chrome seem more reliable.